# Can't dig in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft I can't dig, I've been searching it up and I found it you have to change your world to Survival and it didn't work.

Comment: What tool are you using and what are you trying to break? Is this your own world or a server? By "it didn't work" do you mean you weren't able to change your world to survival or that changing your world to survival didn't allow you to dig?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are in Adventure mode. If you've done `/gamemode survival` and it still doesn't work, please provide more details as to what tool you're using and what you're trying to break.

If that command doesn't work because you don't have permission, you can enable cheats by opening your world as a LAN world and enabling cheats, and that should allow you to run the command.

If you're on a server that you don't have permission on but you should be able to break stuff in, contact whoever is running the server or a server admin.

If you're on an Adventure / minigame server then... there's nothing wrong and your mining ability is disabled by design.